# How to invoke a shell script with flags/switches from java

Tags: java, bash, shell

I have a shell script say for eg testDB.sh which takes up credentials(arguments) in the form of switches/flags. For eg to execute this script I do the following

./testDB.sh -u username -p password.

In order to invoke it from java, i follow the traditional methodology.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"bash","/<path to test script>/testDB.sh","<username>","<password>"});
```

The above doesn't seem to help the cause :(

I would like to know how to invoke this script by passing arguments in the form of flags/switches from java. How do i pass this -u and -v switches ?? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: pass them just as you would a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the flags as well:

```
new ProcessBuilder("<script path>/testDB.sh",
  "-u", username,
  "-p", password
);
```

I strongly suggest against any of the other solutions since they are brittle and will fail suddenly when you have spaces somewhere in any of the script's arguments.

Comment: spaces in a password or a username are quite unusual

Comment: @mithrandir: My Facebook user name has a space and I always try to use space in passwords because it's such an uncommon character - most cracking tools don't try it. What's worse is that people use patterns and the "concat everything into a string and hope" is a very bad pattern to unlearn.

Comment: point taken - I did not know that ProcessBuilder handles spaces correct and Runtime not

Comment: @mithrandir: Actually, the `String[]` version of `exec()` does the same but you have to pass each argument as an individual string. As soon as you join them into one, you're adding a source of subtle bugs to your code.

Answer (score 1):

If both password and username are stored in variables I would suggest you try:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("<script path>/testDB.sh -u " + username + " -p " + password);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not too much of an extension of what you have at the moment. You currently have...

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"bash","/<path to test script>/testDB.sh","<username>","<password>"});
```

Update that to

```
String command = String.format( "/<path to test script>/testDB.sh -u %s -p %s", username, password );
String[] cmdAndArgs = { "/bin/bash", "-c", command };

Runtime.getRuntime().exec( cmdAndArgs );
```

Comment: Note that this breaks in all kinds of ways when the arguments of the script contains spaces.

Comment: Just the one way: badly. :) If you needed to use spaces in arguments it would be easy enough to wrap the %s locations with single quotes.

Comment: ... and escape those properly.

Comment: And at that point think about just incorporating the external functionality into the application.